# Numpy: Need most efficient way to process select elements in a 1D ndarray, using mappings from a 2D ndarray, to output a 1D mean ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time-complexity, mean

First of all, this is not a homework problem; it is an abstraction of a real problem related to my work. I really appreciate any and all input!

I need to run a calculation similar to the one below, tens of thousands of times in sequence, and it's computation time significantly affects the total duration of my simulation:

In this abstraction:

- I have 60,000 widgets and an array of prices for each widget class,
  “widget_prices”.
- I have a 2D mapping `price_mapping`, where each of the 30,000 rows
  corresponds to the purchase of a basket of these widgets, and each of
  the 60,000 columns corresponds to a widget class consistent with the
  indices of `widget_prices`. `Bool` values of `false` mean the widget was not in the basket, and values of `true` mean they are.
- I want to produce an array with the mean widget price computed for
  each of the 30,000 baskets (for each row of `price_mapping`)

An illustration of the data structures is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXNBo.png)

Below is some code that I wrote, testing 3 different approaches I could think of. The 1st, includes `np.mean` and a regular python list comprehension, the 2nd includes `np.average`, `np.tile`. and element-wise matrix multiplication, and the 3rd includes `np.ma`, `np.tile`, and `np.mean`.

```
import numpy as np
import time

number_of_widgets = 60000
number_of_orders = 30000

widget_prices = np.random.uniform(0, 1, number_of_widgets)
price_mapping = np.random.randint(2, size=(number_of_orders, number_of_widgets), dtype=bool)

# method 1, using np.mean and a python list comprehension
start = time.time()
mean_price_array_1 = np.array([np.mean(widget_prices[price_mapping[i, :]]) for i in range(number_of_orders)])
end = time.time()
print('method 1 took ' + str(end - start) + ' seconds')

# method 2, using np.average, np.tile, and element-wise matrix multiplication
start = time.time()
mean_price_array_2 = np.average(np.tile(widget_prices, (number_of_orders, 1)) * price_mapping, weights=price_mapping,
                                axis=1)
end = time.time()
print('method 2 took ' + str(end - start) + ' seconds')

# method 3, using np.ma (masked array), np.tile, and np.mean
start = time.time()
mean_price_array_3 = np.ma.array(np.tile(widget_prices, (number_of_orders, 1)), mask=~price_mapping).mean(axis=1)
end = time.time()
print('method 3 took ' + str(end - start) + ' seconds')
```

these are the results I get:

```
method 1 took 10.472509145736694 seconds
method 2 took 28.92689061164856 seconds
method 3 took 18.18838620185852 second
```

The 1st has the fastest computation time, but is still too slow for my needs.

Is there any way to improve on the list comprehension?

Thank you in advance!!

-S

Comment: How about : `widget_prices[price_mapping].mean(1)`?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of that. It looks much more elegant, but is actually slower than "method 1." On my computer, using `widget_prices[price_mapping].mean(1)`,  `method 4 took 4.242251634597778 seconds`

Comment: If the number of orders was much larger than the number of widgets then doing one indexing probably will be faster.  Here it's smaller.  There's a bit of trade off between iterations and working with larger arrays.

Comment: So, `price_mapping` would always contain just two numbers 0 or 1?

Comment: @hpaulj: Do you mind elaborating on "one indexing"? In my actual case (not this abstracted version),  I actually always have fewer 'orders' than 'widgets.' Does that affect possibilities for speed-ups?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, price_mapping can only be 0 or 1.

Comment: Are you sure? Because that means you are not using those 60000 elements in `widget_prices` and just using the first 2 elements.

Comment: @Divakar: aw man you're right. I messed up when I was framing this problem. the mapping should be bool: true or false! 1 minute as I edit the question and code. Thanks for catching that (it's extremely important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `price_mapping` as a boolean mask that selects elements off `widget_prices` per iteration, we can simply use `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for a vectorized solution and hopefully much faster way, like so -

```
price_mapping.dot(widget_prices)/price_mapping.sum(1)
```

A faster way to do the count of non-zeros per row would be with [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html). Hence, another way would be -

```
price_mapping.dot(widget_prices)/np.count_nonzero(price_mapping, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! This shaves a full second off of the time. I do still wish this would run faster; however, I understand potential computational limits. Any additional ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: @StephenLee Can't think of anything else. It seems you are already on memory limits with those big arrays.

Comment: @StephenLee Also, you can try converting to float before matrix-mult : `price_mapping.astype(float).dot(widget_prices)` and see if this makes some improvement as BLAS based methods are faster with float dtypes.

Comment: Thanks so much! Interestingly, I don't see much of a speed-up from np.count_nonzero vs np,sum, they're about the same. Good to know nontheless!

Comment: interestingly, you're right: converting to float does confer a small boost. I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fast computation and numpy is not helping then i would suggest to use numba.

1) Create a function which uses for loop intead of list comprehension.
2) put @jit decorator at start of method which will run it in parellal on multicore PC.
3) from numba import jit

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try experimenting tomorrow, and explore parallelization here.